# Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS Server not working?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tcpip, internal-dns

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 hosting a DNS server, exchange 2010 and is a domain controller.
One computer on the network (and domain) can ping the server 25% of the time, also when I try to ping it's own hostname it also does not work. However another computer that is on the domain can ping it fine, and another computer on the network but not domain can ping fine as well.

The computer that cannot ping the server is setup to use the DNS server running on the server only (secondary dns points to nothing) and it will resolve the hostname of the server to the external IP not internal when the other two computers correctly resolve the internal

All 3 computers and server are connected directly into the same switch.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Situation has changed a bit, the machine that originally wouldn't ping the server is now working fine, but one of the other 2 that was working now stopped. If I run a dns flush, and release/renew it fixes the issue, which pushes me toward the DNS server or DHCP server/gateway which runs IPCop but would like to hear what people think

Comment: Also: If I don't do the dns flush and ipconfig /release /renew and just wait it will eventually just start working. All of this started after a power outage. Once a successful ping is made however and i set it to continuous ping there will be no issue as long as it's pinging. However if I don't keep pinging and instead wait awhile it will stop working again.

Comment: are the workstations configured to register in dns?  this is in the settings for your network card, go into properties for the protocol and there is a checkbox at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try all your PINGs with IP addresses only.  i.e.: are you experiencing name resolution problems, or TCP/IP problems?

You also say that all three computers are on the same switch - what are their IP addresses and subnet masks?

Comment: I was experiencing both name resolution issues and TCPIP, I have the name resolution problem fixed but not TCP/IP problems. The IP addresses and subnet masks are:
Server:
192.168.0.3
255.255.255.0
PC 1:
192.168.0.9
255.255.255.0
PC 2
192.168.0.150
255.255.255.0

Comment: All machines on the same subnet then.  I would check whether the Windows firewall is enabled, and then start looking at physical causes (cables, Etc).

Comment: Make sure it's not an IPv6 issue; I've seen it cause problems.

Comment: As rsmith said, I've seen this issue w/ IPv6 enabled. try to disable IPV6 on all servers involved. DNS is so simple, it usually doesnt break. it's always something else.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try changing the port used on the switch (or a new switch altogether) in the event the power outage damaged the switch ports.

Answer (score 0):

Do an `ipconfig` when it's working, and then do another when it's not.  I wonder if there's a rogue DHCP server handing out the wrong DNS servers.